# Group rows Keeping the Order of values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

How can I group following set of data:

```
DATENO    COL1   COL2
  1         A      1     
  2         B      1
  3         C      1
  4         C      1
  5         D      1
  6         C      1
  7         D      1
  8         D      1
  9         E      1
```

To get something like this:

```
DATENO    COL1   COL2
  1        A      1     
  2        B      1
  3        C      2
  5        D      1
  6        C      1
  7        D      2
  9        E      1
```

Sum for C and D are grouped keeping the order intact. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there another column that manages the order, or is that the "natural order" of the rows? Note that the "natural order" isn't something to be relied upon. Even if it works consistently in 9i it could break if you upgrade.

Comment: Ed, there is another Date column that can be used for ordering. All I want is not to group all Cs into one group and all Ds into one group, If I am ordering by date column I want to maintain the order but group only the COL1 values that appear consecutively.

Comment: Can there be any number of consecutive C's or 2 at most?

Comment: I am afraid no, there can be any number of consecutive values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** answer corrected according to comments.

Rows can be grouped as required on such a way:

```
-- leave only first rows of each group and substitute col2 with a sum.
select 
  dateno, 
  col1, 
  group_sum as col2 
from (
  -- Get sum of col2 for each bucket 
  select 
    dateno, 
    col1, 
    is_start, 
    sum(col2) over (partition by bucket_number) group_sum
  from (
    -- divide rows into buckets based on previous col1 change count
    select
      dateno, col1, col2, is_start, 
      sum(is_start) over(order by dateno rows unbounded preceding) bucket_number
    from (
      -- mark rows with change of col1 value as start of new sequence 
      select
        dateno, col1, col2,
        decode (nvl(prev_col1, col1||'X'), col1, 0, 1) is_start
      from (
        -- determine for each row value of col1 in previous row. 
        select 
          dateno, 
          col1, 
          col2,
          lag(col1) over (order by dateno)  prev_col1
        from t 
      )  
    )  
  )
)
where is_start = 1
order by dateno
```

Example at [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95904/10)

Comment: ThinkJet, Thanks for your detailed reply. Use of Rank () function makes sense but I would really like to group only consecutive values together. e.g: if you notice in the desired result, there are two Cs in COL1, if I use one of your methods the result set groups all the Cs into one row. Same is the case with Ds.

Comment: @user1242643 Sorry for misunderstanding. I changed an answer, and now I hope that SQL code do what you asked for.