# Need to group sequence of letters while keeping the order in pandas or/and python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql

I have a dataframe :

```
row1 col1 col2

1    U    1
2    U    1
3    U    1
4    D    1
5    D    1
6    U    1
7    U    1

When I did groupby sum I got :

    col1  col2
1     U     5
2     D     2

But what I want is :

      col1  col2

1       U     3
2       D     2
3       U     2
```

someone answered a similar question. but using oracle sql. I only have pandas and python available.

[Group rows Keeping the Order of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987174/group-rows-keeping-the-order-of-values)
[done with sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XIHo.png)

How can I get achieve the output.

Comment: Instead of images, how about you paste the same here ??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before you write anything more here, please read through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @Super Programmer, no pics doesn't work in pandas, people tend to copy your data and work on the solution, since you are member since today I have updated the question. Next time add the text, we dont want images.

Answer (score 0):

Groupby by checking if first row is not equal to second rows. i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['U','U','D','U','U'],'col2':[3,1,2,1,1]})
mask = df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift()).cumsum()
ndf = df.groupby(mask).agg({'col1':'first','col2':'sum'})

     col1  col2
col1           
1       U     4
2       D     2
3       U     2
```